# i have three datetimepicker how to check not duplicate entry in all three field jquery

Tags: jquery

[screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsdgN.png)

See we need third row duplicate.
because first row range all ready define.

How to validate in jquery.

I have three datetimepiker in jquery.

for example:
------   start-time        End-time 
Date:1   2016/05/27 15:00  2016/05/27 18:00
 
Date:2   2016/05/26 15:00  2016/05/26 18:00
 
Date:3   2016/05/27 16:00  2016/05/27 17:00

In that case Date:3 already exist. because same date range in Date:1

How to validate in jquery.

this are many more. so that please make dynamic.

any Idea ???

Comment: Please can you explain a bit in detail or setup fiddle for what you have tried

Comment: See here you will get a [direction](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below script for your problem.

for(i=1;i<6;i++){
    if(( $("#start_time_"+i).val() == '' && $("#end_time_"+i).val() != '' )|| ( $("#start_time_"+i).val() != '' && $("#end_time_"+i).val() == '')){
        alert("Please enter start time/end time.");
        return false;
    }
    for(j=i+1;j<=6;j++){
        if((Date.parse($("#start_time_"+i).val()) <= Date.parse($("#start_time_"+j).val()) || Date.parse($("#start_time_"+i).val()) <= Date.parse($("#end_time_"+j).val())) && ( Date.parse($("#end_time_"+i).val()) >= Date.parse($("#start_time_"+j).val()) || Date.parse($("#end_time_"+i).val()) >= Date.parse($("#end_time_"+j).val()))){
           alert("Both switches coming in same time range.");
            $("#start_time_"+j).val('').focus();
            $("#end_time_"+j).val('');
            return false;
        }
    }
}